# XAMPPのMySQLが起動しない

Tags: mysql, xampp

XAMPPのコンパネより「start」をクリックしても
一瞬runningになりますが、すぐにエラーが出てstoppedになってしまいます。

```
5:19:43  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
5:19:43  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
5:19:45  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
5:19:45  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
5:19:45  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
5:19:45  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
5:19:45  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:19:45  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:19:45  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
5:19:45  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

エラーログmysql_error.logをみると

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size to 10 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size is now 10 MB.
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=17992
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-12-25  5:19:43 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

**いくつか試したこと**

- portcheck.batなどでチェックしてもポートがかぶっている様子はありません。ポートを他のものに変えてみましたが、起動しませんでした。
- xampp > mysql > my.iniの

  ```
  # default-character-set=utf8
  ```

  をコメントアウトしました。
- xampp > mysql > data の中のib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1など削除してから試しましたが、起動しません。
- xamppをアンインストール→再インストールでうごいた　という情報をみましたが、そちらはすでにxamppのhtdocs内でウェブサイトを運営しているので、避けたいと思っています。

質問：ほかにどのような対策が考えられるでしょうか？ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご回答いただけると幸いです。

Comment: `mysql_error.log` の `Server socket created on IP: '::'.` の後に何か出力されていないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。何も出力されていません。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/231603

Comment: 何か別の情報が得られるかと思いましたので、あちらでも質問させていただきましたが、いけなかったでしょうか？
もしそうでありましたら、大変もうしわけございませんでした。
ご覧のように再インストールがいいのかもしれないなと思っております。

Comment: 特に禁止されていませんし気にしないで下さい。

Comment: 参考 [マルチポストとはなんですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/)

Comment: 大変時間がかかってしまいましたが、XAMPPを再インストールすることで解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

XAMPPを再インストールすることで解決しました

---

*この投稿は [@atsushi_kane さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61749/xampp%e3%81%aemysql%e3%81%8c%e8%b5%b7%e5%8b%95%e3%81%97%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment67878_61749) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*